# React Redirect in v6?useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, mern, react-dom

I want to simply redirect the user to '/login' who is not logged in and tries to go a route that is designed for logged in user. Vice versa but redirect to '/'

I heard that react-router-v6 does things differently , even tried using chatGPT who just kept me going in a bunch of loops for different error.

```
[navigate just refers to useNavigate() ]
let routes;
          if (isLoggedIn) {
            routes = (
              <React.Fragment>
                <Route exact path="/" element={<Searchbar changeHeader={setHeader} />} />
                <Route path="/Result" element={<Result changeHeader={setHeader} topic={header} />} />
                <Route path="/Chatbox/:sID" element={<Chatbox />} />
                <Route path="/Assist" element={<Assist changeHeader={setHeader} />} />
                navigate('/')
              </React.Fragment>
            );
          } else {
            routes = (
              <React.Fragment>
                <Route exact path="/" element={<Searchbar changeHeader={setHeader} />} />
                <Route path="/Result" element={<Result changeHeader={setHeader} topic={header} />} />
                <Route path="/Login" element={<LoginForm />} />
                navigate('/login')
              </React.Fragment>
            );
        }
        this is the return component 
         return (
            <AuthContext.Provider value={{ isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn, login: login, logout: logout }}>
              <Router>
              
                <div className="App">
                  {/* This is the main NAVBAR */}
                  <Navbar header={header} headersetter={setHeader} />
        
                  <div className="aSearch">
                    <Routes>
                      {routes}
                    </Routes>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Router>
            </AuthContext.Provider>
          );
        }
        
        I tried using useHistory() but that wouldn't be possible cause not all routes have already been visited. Tried to use bunch of if conditions but made the code way messier
```

Comment: Why are you trying to call `navigate()` within the JSX?

Comment: that was because I just wanted the user to be navigated if they try to react a route that they're not suppose to if they're logged in or not.

Answer (score -1):

Are there any reasons for using context in your router? It seems like something weird to me.

```
<Route
  path="page1"
  element={
    <PrivateRoute isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}>
      <Page1 />
    </PrivateRoute>
  }
/>
```

It is PrivateRoute :

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ isLoggedIn, children }) => {
  if (!isLoggedIn) {
    return <Redirect path="/login"/>
  }
  return children
}
```

Comment: I'm using context here just to keep global track of those parameters.